# How to find the position of a letter in a string in python

Tags: python, character-encoding

I need to find the location of any letter that will be provid by the user.
But it's esentiel that we can't use the commands: Index, enumerate .
So I need to use both strings that we have in the beginning and after that the definition will be used to code files and sentences !

how do i foud the position of the letter in my both strings ?
That's what I have tell now

```
lowers_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
uppers_letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
letter=str(input('pleas tape a letter: '))
def find_number_ofletter(letter):
    return ord(letter) - 97




if __name__ == '__main__':
    if letter in (lowers_letters or uppers_letters):
        find_number_ofletter(letter)
    else:
        print('pleas try again')
```

Comment: Why would you not use index or enumerate?

Comment: The return is not working but probably the problem is the def in the begining

Comment: I was ask to do it without .lower/.upper/index/enumerate/ .find

Comment: You're aware that the statement `if letter in (lowers_letters or uppers_letters):` it's only checking whether the letter is in `lowers_letters`, right?

Comment: yeh but let say i want them to be part of my loop even if i have to change everthings.. what im trying to do is to know the position of a letter in thoses two strings. Once it work. it to use it for a page of text and after that to de encoding text EVEN that i know python have already some keys world to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `find` method.

For example:

```
string_to_search = "this is the string we will be searching"
letter_to_look_for = "a"

index_of_letter = string_to_search.find(letter_to_look_for)
```

To stay with your additional comment that you cannot use `find` as well, this is how I would do it:

```
string_to_search = "this is the string we will be searching"
letter_to_look_for = "a"
index = 0

for letter in string_to_search:
   if letter == letter_to_look_for
       break
   else
       index += 1
```

And at the end of that loop, `index` will be the index of the character you are looking for.

Comment: well done! and i was trying to do it without the find or index but i will try and if i have more questions i will put it in another post